# Rendering items in row with React Native flat list and sticky headers

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native Flat List to render out a list with sticky headers. It seems like the sticky headers and the list items all live in the same container, thus preventing me from adding `flexDirection: 'row'` to the list items only.

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.header) {
        return (
            <ListItem itemDivider style={{backgroundColor: '#87cefa'}}>
                <Body>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                        {item.name}
                    </Text>
                </Body>
            </ListItem>
        );
    } else if (!item.header) {
        return (
            <ListItem style={styles.fridgeItemContainer}>
                <Card style={styles.fridgeItem}>
                    <Icon name='md-pizza' style={{fontSize: 60, color: 'red'}} />
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </Card>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }
};

<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    stickyHeaderIndices={this.state.stickyHeaderIndices}
    numColumns={1}
/>
```

**Current outcome**
[image: Current outcome]

**Desired outcome**
[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Put one header and two list item in a single element and in renderItem method use that single item for render.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mind giving an example please?

Comment: I can't give a good example bcs I don't know your data but I will try to explain.
In your renderItem method instead of if expression return one header and two list item. Create a layout for that and return. And for that you may need make some changes in your data.

Comment: This would not work. RenderItems() loops through an array of data, passing one item into renderItem() at a time. Data format looks like so: `data: [{header:true, name:'someName'}, {header:false, name:'someName'}]`

Comment: If you have a header and some items in it mean that you have some groups of data (at least I understand like this) so you can group your data like this. `[{"header" : "Header1","items": [{"name":"name1"},{"name" : "name2"}]},{"header":"Header2","items": [{"name":"name3"},{"name" : "name4"}]}]`